# How to predict gam random field markov model to grid?

Tags: r, spatial, gam, mgcv, markov-random-fields

I am working on a similar problem as the example in the mgcv package.

I have created a similar model and would like to predict to grid level instead of the districts identified in the training data. Is this possible? If so, how?

I have created a prediction dataset as an example.

```
library(mgcv)
data(columb)
data(columb.polys)

b <- gam(crime ~ s(district,bs="mrf",xt=xt),data=columb,method="REML")
plot(b,scheme=1)


#Create prediction dataset

df <- data.frame(district=numeric(0),x=numeric(0),y= numeric(0)) #Create empty df to store x, y and IDs for each polygon

# Extract x and y coordinates from each polygon and assign district ID
for (i in 1:length(columb.polys)) {
  district <- i-1
  x <- columb.polys[[i]][,1]
  y <- columb.polys[[i]][,2]
  df <- rbind(df,cbind(district,x,y)) 
}

sp <- df %>%
  group_by(district) %>%
  do(poly=dplyr::select(., x, y) %>%Polygon()) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do(polys=Polygons(list(.$poly),.$district)) %>%
  {SpatialPolygons(.$polys)}


#Convert sp to sf object
sp_sf <- st_as_sf(sp, proj4string='+proj=utm +zone=48N +ellps=WGS84 +units=m')
sp_sf <- st_set_crs(sp_sf, '+proj=utm +zone=48N +ellps=WGS84 +units=m')

#Make grid
grid <- st_make_grid(sp_sf, 
                           cellsize = 0.05, 
                              what = "centers", crs = '+proj=utm +zone=48N +ellps=WGS84 +units=m')

#intersection of grid and Columbus, Ohio
pred_grid <- st_intersection(grid, st_buffer(sp_sf, dist=0))

pred_b <- predict(b, pred_data)

Error in data[[txt]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with the MRF, at least so far as I know. In the model you show, you only have the MRF smooth, so the conditional distribution of the response is modelled as estimated values for each `district` under the constraint that the nearby districts are similar to one another-ish. To use the model you need to predict for the districts, not some other data.

I'm assuming in this line

```
pred_b <- predict(b, pred_data)
```

you meant

```
pred_b <- predict(b, pred_grid)
```

If your real problem has a mixture of data on a grid and at a region level, you can predict on the grid, but you'll need to assign each grid location to a region so that you can pass in a column like `District` which is what feeds into the the MRF term.